# How to add node to a view from a different class in Swift

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, sknode

I have a SKScene named GameScene. Normally when I'm working in that class I can add children nodes to the view with: `self.addChild(...)` However, I want to add a node from a different class. I tried `GameScene().addChild(...)` but that didn't seem to work. Any suggestions?

Comment: `GameScene()` creates a **new** GameScene. You probably want to keep your reference to an existing scene.

Comment: Can you please clarify? Why would you want to add nodes, while not even being in the GameScene?

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the current instance of the game scene in order to add children to it. `GameScene()` is just the method that initializes a new scene, but has nothing to do with the current scene that you are using.

Instead, you could go back to the place where it was initialized (likely in the View Controller) and initialize your other class in there (the one you want to add children from). Change the constructor so that you can pass in that instance of the GameScene and keep it as like a property/variable of the class that you want to call from. Then, use it like a variables and add all the children you want.

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your file where the node has to be added to:

`addChild(OtherClass().functionWhereYouAddTheNodes())`

That worked for me.

Rail.